# Angular 8 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

llevo ya un rato intentando solucionar este problema, pero no he podido, agradezco su colaboración.

Problema: Tengo una variable declarada boolean para mostar un spinner de carga obtengo el siguiente error:

ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. at NgForOf.ngDoCheck

la forma como la declaro

```
  cargando: boolean =false;
```

por medio de un *ngIf valido si es true o false para mostrar

```
          <div *ngIf="cargando" class="alert text-center mt-3 animated fadeIn faster">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Cargando...</h4>
            <p>
              <i class="fa fa-sync-alt fa-spin fa-3x"></i>
            </p>
            <p class="mb-0">
              Espere por favor
            </p>
          </div>
```

no se que me haga falta ps ya la acción de pasarla a true lo hago cuando se ejecuta la funcion de obtener información.

este error tambien se presenta al obtener un listado de actividades a mi servicio.
Uso el *ngFor para ciclar el objeto actividad.

yo declaro la variable actividad de esta forma

actividad: any = {};

```
                <button *ngFor="let itemActividad of actividad;let i = index" type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click)="addListActividad(itemActividad, i)">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                <div class="col-md-11 text-capitalize"> {{itemActividad.nombre}} </div>
              </div>
            </button>
```

aca la funcion.

```
  listadoActividades(){
this.cargando = true;
this.servicios.getActividad()
.subscribe( (data) => {
  this.actividad = data['actividades'];
  this.cargando = false;
  console.log(this.actividad);
});
```

}

mirando el console de this.actividad obtengo esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer este error sale cuando el dato que estas iterando no es un array. Puedes poner que es lo que contiene la variable `this.actividad` en el `subscribe`? `console.log(this.actividad)`

Comment: si ya lo puse, estoy atento a tus comentarios gracias por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Según lo visto el problema era la forma como se declaro la variable actividad
la forma correcta en mi caso fue así.

```
  actividad: any = [];
```

con esto se quita el error en la consola